# Hide the list of values from usage - click

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm using `click.Choice` to determine if the value passed to the command's option exists in a list.

The list is very long and when printing the usage message, it makes it very hard to read.

Is it possible to use `click.Choice` and not display the list of all possible values in the usage message?

I know I can validate it without using `click.Choice` but if there's a way of doing it with click it will be better.

Answer (score 4):

The [`click.Option()`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/options/#choice-options) class takes a [`metavar`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#parameters) parameter to allow displaying arbitrary text in the help message.

#### Code:

```
@click.option('--a_choice', metavar='MY_AWESOME_CHOICES', type=click.Choice(a_long_list))
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--a_choice', metavar='MY_AWESOME_CHOICES',
              type=click.Choice([str(j) for j in range(30)]))
def cli(a_choice):
    click.echo("'{}': {}\n".format(cmd, a_choice))

cmds = (
    '--help',
    '--a_choice 5',
    '--a_choice 10',
)

for cmd in cmds:
    try:
        cli(cmd.split())
    except Exception:
        raise
    except:
        pass
```

#### Test Results:

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --a_choice MY_AWESOME_CHOICES
  --help                         Show this message
                                 and exit.
```

---

```
'--a_choice 5': 5
```

---

```
'--a_choice 10': 10
```